# Notation – existential quantificator for more elements

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

How would I properly write down "There exists some $a$ and there exists some $b$ such that $ab = z$."?

Would it be $(1)$
$$\exists a, b: \, ab=z$$
or $(2)$
$$\exists a,\,\exists b:\, ab=z$$
or $(3)$
$$(\exists a)\land (\exists b):\, ab=z$$
or something else?

Comment: My choice would be (2) without the comma, although the comma isn't doing any particular damage to the readability.  (1) is too informal and (3) is just straight-up wrong.

Comment: you can use $1)$ or $2)$ but not $3)$

Comment: I think the answer depends on the convention you choose to use. For instance, in one (very formal) convention none of the three options would work but $\exists a\exists b =\cdot abz$ will. In this case (3) is not more wrong than (1) or (2): none of them is a formula but one is still most likely to interpret each of them correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both (1) and (2) are fine and widely used. (3) is completely wrong.

(2) is slightly more formal than (1), because in formal logic only (2) (without ":") is a well formed formula. 
But this is a matter of taste, because the (widely accepted) convention is that (1) is a shortcut for (2). And the use of ":" after an existential quantification $\exists x$ is widely accepted as well, to improve the readability of the expression.

Note that (3) is an abstract nonsense: the connective $\land$ ("and") should be used to connect two propositions, but $\exists a$ and $\exists b$ are not propositions.